# Remember password autofill in chrome overlays on floating label

Tags: reactjs, floating-labels

I am using the `floating-label-react` library for my forms. It works fine except for one situation. It looks like this if any username and password are previously saved in chrome. But works fine in Mozilla.

[image]

Here is my code for creating this form. I am also using `react-bootstrap`.

```js
<InputGroup>
    <InputGroup.Prepend>
         <InputGroup.Text>
             <i className="icon-communication_mail_24px" />
         </InputGroup.Text>
    </InputGroup.Prepend>

    <FloatingLabel name="email" placeholder="Email" type="text"
                   onChange={this.handleChange} value={this.state.email}
     />
</InputGroup>

<InputGroup>
    <InputGroup.Prepend>
        <InputGroup.Text>
            <i className="icon-action_lock_24px" />
        </InputGroup.Text>
    </InputGroup.Prepend>

    <FloatingLabel name="password" placeholder="Password" type="password" required
                   onChange={this.handleChange} value={this.state.password}
     />
</InputGroup>
```

Any workaround for this will be really helpful.

Comment: Could you add ternary operator at placeholder ? . E.g.: `placeholder={this.state.password ? "" : "Password"}`

Comment: Won't that remove the label entirely? I intend to keep the label at the top of the field.

Comment: Does the label go on top when clicked somewhere on the page?

Comment: Yes it does after clicking.

Comment: It is the issue with the library: https://github.com/mike-engel/floating-label-react/issues/7

Comment: Either use a hack like using ref for click or use another library that has active contributors.

Comment: Can you suggest any good library for implementing this feature?